# Is this blackberry or rose sprout?

Tags: identification, roses, blackberry

I had climbing rose next to this. Late last year I pulled a bunch of seeds and buried near this area:

[image]

I am in Pacific Northwest.

Is it blackberry or rose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are leaves of a rose. [This photo](https://www.jeffpippen.com/plants/rubus-090615-9007durhamz.jpg) is a decent image of a blackberry leaf. Note that the leaflets are irregularly shaped, with the first pair larger than the second pair, unlike a rose where the first and second pair of leaflets are nearly the same size. The red edges of your leaflets are also typical of roses.